# Can a ST-LINK/V2 be driven from UART?

Tags: stm32, st-link

I'm developing an automatic test system that needs to send a program to a STM32 chip. In the past, I've done this using the internal bootloader using one of the UARTs.

However, in this case I only have access to the SWD pins. I can use a ST-LINK/V2 to program the STM32 chip, but I need a PC for this. Is there a way I can still use ST-LINK but without a PC?

Something like: connecting the USB from the ST-LINK to a "USB to UART" chip, and then using UART to drive the programmer?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible but unlikely that it is worth even considering. But basically this is a question how to use an electronic product, and you need an USB host for that. How much you are able to budget time and money designing and writing custom stuff instead of spending 50 dollars/euros for a mini computer that is a PC and can run the ST-Link as usual?

Comment: Hi @Justme, thank you for your response. The difficulty of the task is primarily the basis of my question. If it's going to be time consuming, then there's no point developing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use an [XStreamPro-Iso](https://www.elprotronic.com/collections/xstreampro-iso-adapter) production flash programmer.

This tool can be used for batch programming in a stand-alone mode. The firmware binary is loaded onto an SD card, and can be programmed onto the MCU using a button.

If you need to fully automate this process, you can open up the enclosing and emulate the button press.